# Nei's gene diversity - calculation

Tags: genetics, statistics, biodiversity

I am completely new to biodiversity.

I have a question: how do I calculate Nei's gene diversity?

The formula I was given is **H = 1 – Σpi2**

I have an excel file with 3 different loci (Pgi-2, Pgd-2, Pgm-1). I will attach a screenshot of the table as I have no idea what I have to do. How do I calculate H for the loci?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details and then delete or [edit] your post accordingly. In particular, this doesn't seem to be a question about biology as defined in the help — instead you appear to be asking about how to apply a formula. Who gave you the formula and is there some reason why you haven't asked them? Note that prior research is expected for all questions on this site, so this seems to be doubly off-topic.

Comment: It seems like you need to determine the value of $\pi^2$ for each locus, sum them, and subtract from 1. For ideas of how to estimate nucleotide diversity ($\pi$) see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleotide_diversity). Also: your question would be significantly easier to understand if you used the built-in LaTeX math tools, or really any unambiguous math notation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is: 1) not about biology as defined in the help; 2) shows insufficient  evidence of prior research; and 3) lacks clarity.

Comment: The formula you were given is not Nei's genetic diversity.

Comment: Rather $$1 - \sum_{i=1}^R p_i^2$$ is the [Gini-Simpson index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_index#Gini%E2%80%93Simpson_index). $R$ is the richness, or equivalently the number of genotypes in the data. Each $p_i$ is the frequency probability of the $i$th genotype.

Comment: You can find a description of Nei's genetic score [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_distance#Nei's_standard_genetic_distance).

Comment: What are the integers in row 3 of the spreadsheet? Different alleles of the same gene?

Comment: Please use markdown instead of images to show us tables. It takes up less server space, and makes it easier for us to show you the calculation on your data. You can copy-paste your data into a table generator, such as [here](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) and just copy paste into your question.

Comment: Do you want to calculate Nei's score, or Gini-Simpson's score? They are not the same.